# Is it possible to imitate python tuples in C?

Tags: c, tuples

I am just curious to know what are the strategies ?
(If the strategies exists).

Comment: In C++, you can use the TR1 <tuple> or the Boost Tuple Library.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but in my case C++ is not an option.

Comment: Python is a dynamic language run on a virtual machine. C compiles down to bare-bones machine code. There's no way you're going to get the exact semantics of a Python tuple in C.

What characteristics of the Python tuple are you looking for? Grouping of an arbitrary amount of constant elements? Multiple assignment? Access by array index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical pattern in C for implementing an object that can hold one of a number of different basic types is to use a `struct` containing one element which is a `union` of the possible basic types that can be stored, and one element which is an `enum` identifying which of those types the `union` is being used for in this case.

Then you could use an array of such objects, perhaps represented as a `struct` containing a number of items, and a pointer to the storage for those items.

e.g. something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum tuple_datatype_e {
    TUPLE_DATATYPE_INT,
    TUPLE_DATATYPE_FLOAT,
    TUPLE_DATATYPE_STRING
} tuple_datatype_t;

typedef struct tuple_item_s {
    tuple_datatype_t datatype;
    union {
        int   int_val;
        float float_val;
        char *string_val;
    } u;
} tuple_item_t;

typedef struct tuple_s {
    unsigned int n_items;
    tuple_item_t *items;
} tuple_t;

static void print_tuple(tuple_t *t)
{
    unsigned int i;

    printf("(");
    for (i = 0; i < t->n_items; i++) {
        if (i > 0)
            printf(", ");
        switch (t->items[i].datatype) {
        case TUPLE_DATATYPE_INT:
            printf("%d", t->items[i].u.int_val);
            break;
        case TUPLE_DATATYPE_FLOAT:
            printf("%f", t->items[i].u.float_val);
            break;
        case TUPLE_DATATYPE_STRING:
            printf("\"%s\"", t->items[i].u.string_val);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf(")\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    tuple_t foo;

    foo.n_items = 3;
    foo.items = malloc(sizeof(tuple_item_t) * foo.n_items);
    foo.items[0].datatype = TUPLE_DATATYPE_INT;
    foo.items[0].u.int_val = 123;
    foo.items[1].datatype = TUPLE_DATATYPE_FLOAT;
    foo.items[1].u.float_val = 4.56;
    foo.items[2].datatype = TUPLE_DATATYPE_STRING;
    foo.items[2].u.string_val = "789";
    print_tuple(&foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 but a) I would write helper functions to handle the creation and management of tuples, b) you should use `size_t n_items` instead of `unsigned int n_items`, and c) typenames that end with `_t` are reserved, so you should use a different convention.

Answer (score 3):

The closest to Python tuples in C is probably either structs or arrays, depending on how you will use them.

Use structs if you want to group a fixed number of related values of possibly different types.

Use arrays if you want a number of values of the same type and the ability to index into the array.

Comment: Is it possible to define structs with a variable number of values (of different types) ? Maybe using a MACRO ?

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly the same, a const array has at least some of the same properties. If you require more exact emulation, an ADT could do the trick.

Comment: What's an ADT. (for what I know ADT stands for Abstract Data Type).

Answer (score 1):

There the LinuxTuples in C with an API

http://linuxtuples.sourceforge.net/